# What is automatically "cached" when rendering a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, ruby-on-rails-5

Let's say we have these two outputs in a view:

```
@post.user.first_name

current_user.posts.size
```

If the outputs above would be called multiple times each in a single view, is Rails "smart enough" to not hit the database every time?

**If the answer is yes** - are there any "general rule" about this worth knowing?

**If the answer is no** - would a good practice then be to store the associated object/objects in it's own variable?

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord by default [caches queries for performance](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching). If you do AC query in console a few times you will see that the second query executes much faster due to AC cache. So I guess this works for queries in the view as well.

You can manually cache objects with Rails [Fragment Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) feature.

> Fragment Caching allows a fragment of view logic to be wrapped in a
>   cache block and served out of the cache store when the next request
>   comes in.

Also there is [Cache Stores](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores) for you to use.

> Rails provides different stores for the cached data (apart from SQL
>   and page caching).

Answer (score 0):

Queries for a view are done in the controller action that renders the view. You will notice that you define `@post` in your controller action but you may not see `current_user` defined. This is typically because you're using the devise gem and the code defining the `current_user` method is part of the gem.

Everything you need to render a view should be queried in your controller by `ActiveRecord` and in memory of the app in preparation of the rendering of the view. So multiple calls of @post or current_user shouldn't matter.

Sometimes objects are called via associations for a view eg. `@post.user.name` Is going to have to query for the user. This will work but it is better Model-View-Controller separation to eager load the users along with the posts in the controller. Following MVC and making sure your queries happen in the controller will also help you avoid N + 1 query performance issues. See [Rails Active Record Query Eager Load](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

An example of querying users with their posts.

```
@post = Post.find(post_params).includes(:user)
```

Comment: Thank you for a the run-through. So the answer to my question would probably be - no. I.e. db queries are **not** automatically  "cached", if best practices aren't in place (instance variables for each object and usage of `.includes`) - then we will hit the database much more often.

Comment: Yes, ActiveRecord queries are cached for performance, see Martin Zinovsky's answer, if the queries are identical within the controller action. However if best practices are not in place, and you start requesting associated objects in your template you'll force additional queries and hurt performance.